# Validations Custom - Compare two variables between new and existing objects (dates) Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date

My rails application is a residence application.

I have a model `stay` which is a third model in a has_many:through assocation between a `tenant` and a `flat`. A stay is defined by a `checkin_date` and a `checkout_date`. I would like to create a custom validations to prevent the creation of a new `stay` if there is already a `tenant` in a `flat` for a given period...but i never write a custom validation before so i'm super lost...

By logic, i know i need to compare the checkin_date and checkout_date of the "already existing record" and the "supposed new one". So I guess it would look like : (n+1= the new record vs. n= already existing record)

```
    > def duplicate_stay
    > 
    >  if Stay.exists?(tenant_id: current_tenant.id, studio_id:
    > current_studio.id) && 
    >             checkin_date(n+1) > checkin_date(n)  
    >             checkout_date(n+1) > checkin_date(n)
    >             checkin_date(n+1)  < checkout_date(n)
    >             checkout_date(n+1) < checkout_date(n) 
    > == false 
    >             else 
    > == true (the model can be created)  
end
```

Can someone help me? I keep looking but I know understand how to do it !

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `cover?` method. You can use it like this:

```
today = Date.today
in_one_week = today + 7.days
search_date = today + 3.days

(today..in_one_week).cover? search_date
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but if you added a scope to the `Stay` class:

```rb
scope :overlaps, ->(stay) {
  where(
    tenant_id: stay.tenant_id,
    studio_id: stay.studio_id,
  ).
  where(arel_table[:checkin_date].lt(stay.checkout_date)).
  where(arel_table[:checkout_date].gt(stay.checkin_date))
}
```

... then for an instance of `Stay` `@stay` calling `Stay.overlaps(@stay).exists?` would return true if there was any instance that overlapped with @stay.

Let me know if that doesn't work. It's often helpful to look at the SQL that is executed as part of a validation if you're not sure why something isn't working the way you think it should.

Edit: one tricky thing here is that a stay overlaps with itself, so if `@stay` was saved successfully (ie. it has an `id` assigned) you might have a problem with that logic. You can provide different logic depending on whether the record is saved or not, though.

I think that this would do it:

```
scope :overlaps, ->(stay) {
  logic = where(
    tenant_id: stay.tenant_id,
    studio_id: stay.studio_id,
  ).
  where(arel_table[:checkin_date].lt(stay.checkout_date)).
  where(arel_table[:checkout_date].gt(stay.checkin_date))

  logic = logic.where.not(id: stay.id) unless stay.new_record?

  logic
}
```